# What is the point of having both Model and ViewModel in M-V-VM?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I always find it tempting to put a model and a view-model together in one class, and I don't see the downside of doing that.

There must be a good reason for separating them. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first real downside of doing this is a lack of separation of concerns. And soon this will lead to redundant code. Now, that said, I've seen a lot times where developers have used their Model objects as ViewModels. And if we're totally honest with ourselves, in a very thin app, separating these concepts can actually lead to more redundancy.

The best thing you can do is learn more about MVVM, and its roots in MVC and Presentation Model, but I think it's a great thing that you're asking this question and that you're not blindly following dogma. In fact, I often don't even start with MVVM at all when I begin a small app. I'll often start with a hundred lines or so in the code-behind, proving a concept, and then start refactoring it into MVVM.

**More to the point of your question**, the model and view-model have - in a conceptual sense - very different purposes. The Model includes your business logic (domain logic), data model (objects, attributes and relationships), and data access layer. The ViewModel is essentially an adaptor for the Model, adapting it for the specific purposes of the View. In some cases you might have 3 different views (and view-models) for a given data model object. Each view-model would be adapting those same attributes on the model object for the specific purposes of that particular view.

Answer (score 7):

`ViewModel` is the **soft-copy** of the `View` i.e. if you have a updateable `ListBox` on View, you will have an `ObservableCollection` in your ViewModel that **represents** that list of items in the listbox. Similarly if you have a `Button` on your `View`, the `VM` will hold its `Command`.

`Model` will be actually what has the data that the `View` shows. So the type collection in your `VM` is of, can be termed as a `Model` class.

E.g. a `Employees ListView` is a `View`, and has a data context which is the instance of `EmployeeViewModel` class that has an `ObservableCollection` property of `Employee` class where `Employee` class becomes a `Model`.

Usually there is 1-1 relationship between `View` and `VM` and 1-N relationship between `VM` and `Model`.

Comment: sorry, my English is not good enough to understand this sentence: "So the type collection in your VM is of, can be termed as a Model class." can you explain a little bit more.

Comment: What I meant was if you have a view with employee list box then your view model should have an **ObservableCollection<Employee>** thus your model is **Employee**.

Answer (score 3):

The model is the domain of your application and so contains your domain logic such as business rules and validations. The ViewModel is the model for your view. It handles the interactions between the user and the view, i.e. when the user clicks a button the view model will handle that interaction and may or may not make changes to the model. Normally in an OO language, you want your objects to have a single responsibility only.

In WPF the ViewModel usually implements the INotifyPropertyChange interface which is then observed by the view for any changes. You wouldn't want the model to implement this interface since it is not related to your domain in anyway.

Another reason for separation is that sometimes your view might not necessary show all data that is in the model. For example, if your model exposes 15 properties but in one of your view the user needs to see only 5 of those properties. If you place your model in the ViewModel the view would be exposed to all 15 properties whereas if you encapsulate the model in the ViewModel then only those 5 properties would be exposed to the View.

There are probably many more reasons but in general it is a good design principle to keep them separated. With that being said, if your application is small enough you can get get away with having your model and ViewModel together to reduce redundancy in your code.

Comment: upvoted - I honestly didn't read your answer before I wrote mine, but it looks like we covered some of the same ground. This is a far better answer than the vote leader and gives great specific examples.

Answer (score 2):

My simple answer (and I don't pretend to be [WPF Guru](http://msbdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)) would be that , in WPF, you'd need a VM when:
1. You don't want to expose all your Model to a specific view
2. Your model is not in "WPF style" (doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, no observable collections or no Commands).